# Trying to include file from another account: permissions denied

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, file-permissions

I have a dedicated server running php with dso handler, I am including a global config.php from one account into all the other accounts. This works fine on apache when opening the sites via browser.

But I also have some cron jobs, and there i get "permissions denied" error when trying to include the config.php file.

The main config.php is in user1 account, so I tried adding user2 (which includes user1 config.php) to the user1 group, but that didn't worked, the error still persist.

How could I fix it without having to modify all the files that include the main config.php file?

UPDATE:

i "fixed" it by adding the user2 to the nobody group. It seems to work fine, but could it generate some other problems?

Answer (score 0):

Every web server uses `Effective uid and gid` ,

*Definition :*

```
Effective username and group name are defined in /etc/passwd and /etc/group
```

For example `apache` on `Debian distro` uses `www-data group` and `www-data user`. You should set your web data to them.Such as :

```
chown www-data.www-data YOURROOTDIR/ -R
```

*Suggestion :*

You should find out to how set your distro its `effective uid and gid`.Then act to `chown`.Because each distro uses one `effective uid and gid`.